# create list by -5 and + 5 from given number

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, range

Suppose `num = 10`

want output like `[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]`

Tried : `range(num-5, num) + range(num, num+5)`

Is there an other way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `range`'s start and stop parameters, like this

```
>>> range(num - 5, num + 5)
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do this

```
map(lambda x:x+5, range(10))
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I gotta say the title is a bit misleading.

> create list by -5 and + 5 from given number
>   It makes me beleive that you want `[num-5,...,num, ...,num +5]` which isn't what the example in the main body says.

Anyway, several ways, let's stick with the one using range:

```
num = 10
delta = 5
print range(num-delta, num+delta)
>[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]

#Or, if you want [num-5, ..., num, ..., num+5]
print range(num-delta, num+delta + 1)
>[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
range(num+5)[-10:]
```

Or this:

```
>>> def range5(num):
...     i = num-5
...     nums=[]
...     while i < num+5:
...             nums.append(i)
...             i+=1
...     return nums
... 
>>> range5(10)
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
>>> range5(20)
[15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]
```